# What is the fastest method to check the difference between two json files in Python?

Tags: python

So, I've a JSON file from which I get particular data by doing:

```
user['screen']['username'],update['timestamp']
```

After, I call the file I get the JSON file in the same format but with new data. I want to check if I've got any new data. What I thought of doing is dumping this into a list and then doing a set difference between the old and the new list. I'm having problems regarding that at two places: 
      1. What is the fastest way to dump data into list comprehension? 
      2. Is that a good way to go about it(What is the point of dumping large amount of data when the change in data would be minimum?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is some kind of deep comparison, right?

Maybe this will solve the issue for you: http://code.google.com/p/python-deep/.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird if you just going to get some **particular data** from  **same format**  by compare the whole list. I mean if you already know some part of the dict may change, then you can get or compare them directly.

Why would you want to compare the whole dict?